# infinite redirect loop on loadbalancer of 2 instance aws php

Tags: php, ssl, elastic-load-balancer

I have a site working on load balancer of 2 instances of aws. 
It is working fine in http but when I try it with https it is going in infinite loop and gives error of ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Site is in Yii2

htaccess on both instances

```
     Options -Indexes

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine on
    </IfModule>

    # Deny accessing below extensions
    <Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    </Files>

# Deny accessing dot files
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

Comment: have you changed code of .htaccess file?

Comment: Site is in Yii2 and htaccess is like this on both instances

Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine on
</IfModule>

# Deny accessing below extensions
<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Deny accessing dot files
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]